# Firebase (iOS): Delete User created from Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

To delete users created from email in Firebase using the iOS sdk is easy:

```
myFirebaseRoot.removeUser(user.email, password: user.password, withCompletionBlock: { error in

}
```

But I don't see a method to delete users created from Facebook. Why is this? It's clearly possible to delete Facebook users from the dashboard:

[image]

Anyone know how I can delete Facebook users using the iOS SDK?

**Edit**

Using version 2.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Once you get a `FIRUser` you can call `deleteWithCompletion` on it to delete that user.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user.html#method-detail

Comment: In the 2.x SDK there is no call to remove a user from a social provider (since we didn't keep any persistent information about the user in our auth backend).

Comment: so that's it there's just no way? what were they thinking in version 2.x?

Comment: Since there was no data stored for the user, there was also no need to delete it. Which makes a lot of sense. If you need to delete the user data, you'll need to use a newer SDK.

Comment: What does not make sense is that you can do it from the dashboard but not the code - clearly it's in the API, just not the SDK

Comment: It *is* in the new SDK.

Comment: Was referring to old sdk in previous comment